# How do I pass up the value inside of react-autosuggest to the parent component?

Tags: reactjs

In my app.js, I have this

```
render() {
  return (
    <div id="App">
      <SearchBar />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And inside of SearchBar, I import react-autosuggest and have this -

```
render() {
  const { value, suggestions } = this.state;
  const inputProps = {
    placeholder: "Search",
    value,
    onChange: this.onChange
  };

  return (
    <Autosuggest 
      style={style}
      suggestions={suggestions}
      onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
      onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
      getSuggestionValue={getSuggestionValue}
      renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
      inputProps={inputProps}
      onSubmit={this.doSomething}
      />
  );
}
```

Where all these functions are standard boilerplate functions that react-autosuggest uses.  How do I access what was searched for inside of SearchBar inside of it's parent, app.js?

Answer (score 1):

You can use props to raise the data from the `Autosuggest` events to the parent component. Create a method inside `App` and pass it down as a prop to the `SearchBar` component. Then, call it with the `Autosuggest` event.

**App**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  onSubmit(e) {
    // `e` is the data that was passed through from the `Autosuggest` event.
    console.log(e);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="App">
        <SearchBar onSubmit={this.onSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**SearchBar**

```js
<Autosuggest onClick={this.props.onSubmit} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a callback function at the SearchBar component. Follow the steps below according to your use case:

1. Add below function at SearchBar component

   ```
   onHandleChange(event, value){
     this.setState({ value });
     this.props.getInputData(event, value);
   }
   ```
2. Use above function at AutoSuggest component

   ```
   return (
     <Autosuggest 
       ...
       onChange={(event, value) => this.onHandleChange(event, value)}
       ...
     />

   );
   ```
3. Use SearchBar component like

   ```
   render() {
     return (
      <div id="App">
       <SearchBar getInputData={(event, value) => this.getAutosuggestInput(event, value)}/>
      </div>
     );
   }
   ```
4. Here you get the value of input box at the parent component

   ```
   getAutosuggestInput = (event, value) => {
       //add your logic here
   }
   ```